# string compared to list in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I will be entering a large data set of strs to compare to a dict with lists. For example, the str 'phd' will be compared against strs from this dict

```
   edu_options = {'Completed College' : [ 'bachelor', 'ba', 'be', 'bs'....],
                  'Grad School' : ['phd','doctor'...] }
```

input str comes from edu_dict

```
edu_dict = {
        "A.S":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "AS":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "AS,":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "ASS,":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "Associate":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "Associate of Arts (A.A.),":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "Associate of Arts and Sciences (AAS)":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "B-Arch":"Completed College",
        "B-Tech":"Attended Vocational/Technical",
        "B.A. B.S":"Completed College",
        "B.A.,":"Completed College",
        "B.Arch,":"Completed College",
        "B.S":"Completed College",
        "B.S.":"Completed College",
        "B.S. in Management":"Completed College",
        "B.S.,":"Completed College",
        "BA":"Completed College",... 
    *The list is 169 items similar to this*
    }
```

clean_edu() takes the key from edu_dict, removes the punctuation, spaces...etc. For example 'P.H.D.' becomes 'phd'. If 'phd' matches a str from any of these lists, it should return the correct key, in this case 'Completed Graduate'. For most of the inputs I have put in, the correct value has been returned.

```
def clean_edu(edu_entry):

    lower_case_key = edu_entry.lower() # changing the key to lower case

    chars_in = "-.,')("           #setting the chars to be translated
    chars_out = "      " 
    char_change = "".maketrans(chars_in, chars_out)        # replacing punctuation(char_in) with empty space(char_out)   

    clean = lower_case_key.translate(char_change)      #executing char_change 


    cleaned_string = re.sub(r'\s\s{0,}','',clean).strip()


    return cleaned_string


while user == "":
    for edu_level in edu_options: 
        for option in edu_options[edu_level]:
            if option in cleaned_string: 
                user = edu_level
                return user 

    user = "No match"
```

The problem is that 'bs' is correctly triggered for some of the inputs but not for others. When I print the unmatched str and their comparison

```
print ("Not Detected. Adding to txt" + '\t' + edu_entry + '\t' + cleaned_string + '\t' + option) 

Output: " Not Detected. Adding to txt     business        nursing
```

where bs is the input and l is the comparison str. In edu_options dict there is no value 'l' so I don't understand where this is coming from. This problem didn't occur for input strs such as 'bs biology' or 'bs business'.

Successful run:

input str: 'P.H.D'         output:'Completed Graduate School'

Comment: I think you want `for option in edu_options[edu_level]:` in your third line. As an aside, it might help to invert your dictionary for faster lookups

Comment: that's what I originally had it as and it still produced the same problem

Comment: `This problem didn't occur for input strs such as 'bs biology' or 'bs business'.` because the `e` in `Completed College` is in `bs business` and the `l` in `Grad School` is in `bs biology`. I'd recommend that you post the input, as well as the expected output for that input, so that we can better understand your issue. Also, please show us how you compute `cleaned_string`

Comment: I added all the 'nondetected' keys as well as the clean_edu() and the edu_dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you should return when you find a match in a list, maybe the key of that list?

In that case, this should work:

```
>>> edu_options = {'Completed College' : [ 'bachelor', 'ba', 'be', 'bs'], 'Grad Shool': ['phd', 'doctor']}
>>> cleaned_string = 'phd'
>>> for key, value in edu_options.items():
...     if cleaned_string in value:         # value is the list
...         print key                       # inside a function, use return
...
>>> Grad Shool
```

Edit: I think the mistake is in your second loop, look what happens:

```
>>> edu_options = {'Completed College' : [ 'bachelor', 'ba', 'be', 'bs'], 'Grad Shool': ['phd', 'doctor']}
>>> for edu_level in edu_options: 
...     for option in edu_level:   # Right here
...         print option
... 
C
o
m
p
l
e
t
e
d

C
o
l
l
e
g
e
G
r
a
d

S
h
o
o
l
>>>
```

From there 'l' comes out.

Comment: an example of the desired output from edu_dict: input: 'B-Arch' would be edited by clean_edu() to become 'barch' which would then be compared to the lists in edu_options and return the key if the list contains the str(ex: 'Completed College')

Comment: So, my loop should work isn't it? Though I didn't understand if/elif statements at the end of your code... Anyway, the 'l' value comes from your second loop `for option in edu_level:` in that way `option` becomes each character of the keys in dict.

Comment: your approach does produce some matches but less than my current code. The if elif statements provide a way to break once the correct value has been matched instead of iterating through all parts of the list. Since the data set is going to be very large, this is important

Comment: I'm able to match almost all the items in the edu_dict but it doesn't catch the value 'bs'. When I check what the value 'bs' is being compared to, it comes up as 'l' in all cases

Comment: But when I run your code, it iterates over the keys strings of edu_options dict, not over the lists. Is this what you want? Sorry, I didn't understand yet. However a simple `return key` should be enough to stop the iteration.

Comment: in my code, having iterations through each value of the list in edu_options allows a more accurate comparison of the value to cleaned_str. At least that is what I think based on results from your code suggestion vs mine

Comment: I edited my answer in order to show where I think the mistake is. I guess that you are not having iterations through each value of the lists.

Comment: your exactly right, i changed the code to include "for option in edu_options[edu_level] to get the whole str value. But now it is comparing false options to the cleaned_string. As you can see from the edited outputs on the OP

Comment: Instead of `if option in cleaned_string` try `if option == cleaned_string`. You should get the same output of my code, I guess...

Comment: that works but eliminates matches that occur from partial match. Ex: 'masters'(option) in  'mastersinengineer'(cleaned_string). I don't want to have to enter in every possible value for future big data sets

Comment: So I realized that I hadn't entered some of the strs into edu_options such as '2006' and 'airframe'. The one output error left is 'business' being compared to 'nursing'. I definitely have business in the edu_options. Thanks a lot for your help Marco, it has helped me work through these problems

Comment: You are welcome! Well I think is not a good idea rely on partial match, especially in big data sets, with a small option such as 'be', your condition could become true so easily, even when it shouldn't.

Comment: but then how to create a match in edu_options without accounting for every possible string?

Comment: Well, only in the worst case you need to check every single string. Are you worried about the efficiency? I think that the most efficient (and safe) way to match a str in a list of str is simply `if str in list`, neat and clean! Now that I think, if the values in the lists are unique and you don't need indices, you could use sets instead of lists (they are more efficient).